# Can I ask if a given Fatal Python error is rare enough that it helps the Python community to try to reproduce it?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, closed-questions

I've asked several successful and very specific SO questions with minimal reproducible examples (MRE) and understand the importance of same.

I now have the unusual situation of a screen shot from a few weeks ago that at the time I thought was humorous, but now realize it might be worth tracking down what happened.

I thought it was humorous because I'd never seen "stack overflow" in a Python error message like

```
Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow.
```

Most of us *can* recover from Stack Overflow with a good night's sleep.

Is it impossible to ask https://stackoverflow.com/q/70728180/3904031 on Stack Overflow, or was there some way I could have? (the question is currently deleted, so it's now viewable only to higher-rep users)

I'm clearly not asking what the error is, I'm asking if it's rare enough that I should then go ahead and try to reproduce it so that I can then generate an MRE.

Would this somehow be possible? Would there have been a different way to phrase it?

**note:** I realized that the question's close votes were triggered (at least in part) by the debugging tag, so I've removed that tag. The question itself is not about debugging.

Comment: I don't think it is such a rare error: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Fatal+Python+error%3A+Cannot+recover+from+stack+overflow%22&oq=%22Fatal+Python+error%3A+Cannot+recover+from+stack+overflow%22. So... if yours is not a duplicate, why not just go ahead and post a question? P.s. the comment was written before I clicked the link to the post

Comment: @OlegValter I did, it's linked right in my question here, and it was closed. I'm trying to understand if it could have been asked in a different way such that answers would not have been prevented. Note that the problem happened from within matplotlib, a very actively supported and mature package.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed after posting the comment :) maybe provide the code that is causing the error? Looks like a standard case of recursion run amock

Comment: @OlegValter question (now) asks "Is it uncommon for Matplotlib to throw actual `stack overflow` errors? ***If so*** should I try to go back and figure out what happened here to document it?"

Comment: I do not think "how often" is a good question direction for SO, frankly. It is likely to be closed (rightfully) as opinion-based. Maybe reframe it to be about common causes? My comment above was about addressing the closure for the lack of debugging details - if you want to frame it more generally, I think asking for causes is a better option than asking avout the frequency

Comment: @OlegValter so I think you feel "yes, it is impossible to ask the question" which I want to ask. I think that's a good answer here and you can consider posting it as such. I don't have the debugging details, I am trying to figure out how helpful it would be to the matplotlib development community for me to go back and try to figure out what it was that I'd fixed. SO is not only for debugging errors, there are other types of questions that are more broad and have a variety of answers that are not considered opinion based by the community.

Comment: I would argue that questions about a stack overflow are going to be a lot like null pointer exceptions.  Almost certainly very specific to the situation, and thus unlikely to make for good Q&A.  But, spending time trying to build an MRE at the very least has a good chance to be educational if you have never chased a stack overflow before.

Comment: @StephenRauch I'm 99% sure it was a bad value for a keyword (named) argument passed to a matplotlib method, and it looks like matplotlib then passed it to `abc.py` so the question is if matplotlib should have trapped it or not. I'm getting the distinct impression that my concern for matplotlib is misplaced; I solved my problem by removing the bad value for the argument, perhaps I shouldn't worry about matplotlib not trapping it? Perhaps "do the right thing" is not so appreciated?

Comment: a minimal reproducible example needs more than only a error message only in conunction with source code it is decipherable, so the cliose votes are correct

Comment: @nbk a MRE was not provided. The question is not about how to solve the problem, so it wasn't necessary. The question I am asking is *if it would be worth it to the matplotlib community for me to go back and see if I can reproduce the error so that an MRE could then be generated and a new question asked.* I think the answer to the question here is "No" because these days SO users can't or won't read and so pre-assume that all questions that happen to mention errors must be about solving the error. Most (vtc-ing) users there *were not agile enough* to consider other possibilities.

Comment: @uhoh i help people with their questions , but without a mre i can't help them, your error can come from multiple possibilities and we can't guess which you have used, so closure till you can provide a mre is the only option we have

Comment: Couldn't it be provoked by [squeezing the process' available RAM on, say, Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44985/limit-memory-usage-for-a-single-linux-process)? (Not a rhetorical question.)

Comment: "Should this question be asked on Stack Overflow" isn't a programming question, it's a question about usage of Stack Overflow itself. I agree with the answer below that a Python specific chat room would have been the best place to ask but in general "Is this a good, on-topic question" can be asked on Meta.

Comment: Stack overflows are nearly always infinite recursion errors in managed languages that don't have a max call stack depth (each function call adds stuff to the stack until it overflows, breaking the infinite recursion). Without a minimal reproducible example, it's just speculation, though.

Comment: @ErikA it seems to have happened in a module called by matplotlib, which doesn't normally exhibit fatal errors when a parameter is incorrect. If I can reproduce what I did then it could be trapped in matplotlib and never get passed to the offending module.

Comment: @uhoh Possibly, but detecting infinite recursion is a subcase of the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem). If they have an erroneously infinitely recursing function, they can solve it, but if they allow you to pass one (I'm more familiar with ggplot, which allows user-defined formatting functions, for example) then it may be all on you and not a bug in their code. It all depends on exactly what you were doing.

Comment: @ErikA intended or not, this is convincing me that I should really try to go back and figure out what it was I'd passed that caused this. It may be impossible but now I'm going to have a look.

Answer (score 16):

Disclosure: I voted to close the question.

Looking back after reading this (meta) question and your comments, I realize I might have closed it for the wrong reason. First let me justify my vote: you showed (an image of) an error's stacktrace and asked something about it. Now, it's hard for us to say anything about it without knowing what code produced it... This is why I voted to close it as needing debugging details. As I stated in comments there:

> It could be a simple typo, it doesn't mean something is wrong with the package. We can't know without having a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)...

After reading this meta, I understand that your real question was "***should I*** go back and get a MRE for this?". So maybe my original close reason was wrong, but then this kind of question should just be closed as opinion based. Why? How can we assess your time and whether it is worth it for you to go and reproduce the error? I can't see that as a useful Q&A for future readers to come by... If a question is basically a "should I..." it is most likely opinion based. Your question was a base-work for a follow-up question, which *might* be an on-topic SO question. The "should I" question could, on the other hand, be asked in [the Python chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) where other experts (possibly in matplotlib) could definitely answer you whether you should follow it through or not.

I would say that if/when you go and find a way to reproduce the error, post it as an MRE and the question can be whether something about it should be changed in the package itself. Once again, it's hard to answer that without being able to run it for yourself.

**note:** I didn't even see at the time that the question was tagged with [debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/debugging)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I bounce between several SE sites and ask in SO much less frequently these days, partly because packages like scipy, numpy and matplotlib are so darn mature and easy to use that I don't encounter problems that could be asked about here, so I'm off in SciComp SE, Codereview and the like. So it seems your answer to this question "...is it possible to ask in some way..." your answer is probably "No, not here in SO."

Comment: Any thoughts on why [this bountied question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70704705/3904031) is getting silent downvotes? Could it also be of the type that is impossible to ask in SO?

Comment: To answer your first comment: The answer to the question *"Is it possible to ask 'should I bother myself with going back to reproduce an error?'"* (exaggeration intended) is *"not on any SE site"*. This is purely opinion based. On the other hand, if you just go on and find a MRE for this issue, this is a different matter. You could first ask what happened, how to fix it, and/or is it a bug in matplotlib. Once again, you can always ask questions that are not necessarily on-topic in chat (read the rules first) and package-specific communities (don't know of any specific for matplotlib)

Comment: @uhoh Regarding the second comment, seems like a good question to me. Don't get too bothered with downvotes. Sadly, they sometimes have more reasons then their intended ones. Take a look at my profile and see if you agree with the scores of my first two questions... I got angry at first, I just stopped caring. Back to your question, I'm not an expert in profiling, Mac and other things in your question so it seems to me like again a MRE is missing. But it might not be the case. Just for the record, I didn't downvote your first question as it seemed interesting, just VTC as I explained above